# Is it possible to mark a message / sender as junk for a connected Exchange account?

Tags: email, exchange

The mail client with Windows 8 allows you to mark a message as junk, for a connected Exchange Account - is this possible via the email client on the phone, or are we limited to manually moving to the junk folder (without associating to the junk senders list, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Right now we are limited to manually moving it to the Junk folder by selecting one or more of the email messages and hitting the "move to folder" icon.

However it would be a good idea for MS to add the ability to mark as spam