# Whitelist email sender or mark email as not junk

Tags: email

Emails that are not junk are getting sent to the Junk folder. Is there a way to manually mark a sender as safe (Not Junk)? Or is this supposed to happen automatically if you move emails from the Junk folder to your Inbox?

Comment: See also: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/5498/106

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that post, but I'm trying to do the exact opposite of that.

Comment: I reckon the answer is going to be a bigger no, as you can't flag as spam

Comment: @RowlandShaw well, technically you can, by moving an e-mail inside the junk folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marking e-mails as junk is done by you e-mail provider (i.e. Google, Microsoft, Yahoo, Fastmail, ...) and **not** by your phone.

If you manually move e-mails outside the junk folder to your inbox folder for example, the spam engine running on your e-mail provider's servers *should*, after a time or two, understand that those e-mails are not spam and don't marking them as spam in the future.

Please note that you don't have actual control on this. You would only if the spam filtering would be done on your e-mail client, which is not the case. Usually e-mail providers have on their web mail interface a "mark as not spam" button, but every one is implementing that in different way so there isn't an equivalent button on your e-mail client.

Comment: *"Marking e-mails as junk is done by you e-mail provider"* - that's not entirely correct. The email provider will often add some X-headers with some spam related scores. Its up to the email server and/or client to interpret the scores. Sometimes a server pre-classifies an email based on score by moving to the *Junk* folder. It seems reasonable that some senders should be whitelisted, regardless of what the email filters rate their mail.

Comment: @jww If I have to make an educated guess, I think white-list feature is not coming soon in the WP e-mail client.
In the current App, you can't even flag an e-mail, that is a *very basic* feature; I would consider white-list an advanced one, that probably will never be implemented.
Anyway, thank you for the details on spam managing.